# Call angular UI Bootstrap directive from inside custom directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, directive, angular-bootstrap

currently I'm working on a very extense form and using inputs, textareas, datepickers etc etc on the HTML it will make the code look very ugly and also very hard to read.
The thing is that I have created custom directives that returns the proper HTML element e.g.:

In the HTML

```
<suggest-input data-ng-model="EDCtrl.headerStep.provider.identification"
               placeholder="'Ej. 888888-8'"
               label="'Identificador de emisor'">
</suggest-input>
```

the directive :

```
var suggestInput = function ($compile, $http) {
  return {
     restrict: 'E',
     require: 'ngModel',
     templateUrl: templates + '/suggestInputTemplate.tpl.html',
     replace: true,
     scope: {
         model: '=ngModel',
         label: '=label',
         title: '=title',
         placeholder : '=placeholder'
     },
   };
};
```

the template

```
<div>
  <label>{{ label }}</label>
  <input class="form-control" data-ng-model="model" placeholder="{{ placeholder }}" call="functionName()"/>
</div>
```

and I'm having problems with using a angular bootstrap directive inside my custom directive, for example :
How can I call the "uib-typeahead" using this kind of configuration in my custom directives ?

Any ideas ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular UI directive inside custom directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48654008/angular-ui-directive-inside-custom-directive)

Answer (score 0):

You can use any nested directive inside your own one, and `angular-ui-boostrap` directives are not special in this case. Regarding `uib-typeahead` you can see the following example on the `angular-ui-bootstrap` site:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="asyncSelected" 
   placeholder="Locations loaded via $http" 
   uib-typeahead="address for address in getLocation($viewValue)" 
   typeahead-loading="loadingLocations" 
   typeahead-no-results="noResults" class="form-control">
```

The only important thing to know is that `ngModel` is the directive itself and you can access it via `link(scope, element, attrs,ngModelController)`. ngModelController has `$viewValue` and `$modelValue` properties which are representing the bonded value from outer scope. so instead of 
   `scope:{model:'=ngModel'}` use those variables for bindings inside your directive.

Comment: sorry about this, but I don't see what you are telling me on your comment, can you please provide an example with angular 1.6 ?