# Angular UI directive inside custom directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

[Similar question but the question isn't sufficiently answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42179140/call-angular-ui-bootstrap-directive-from-inside-custom-directive)

In the following code, why doesn't **`uib-datepicker-popup`** turn into an angular UI date picker?

Am I missing some flag/compile option for the directive?

This is a stripped down example of the [datepicker-popup](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#datepickerPopup) example in the Angular-UI documentation, modified to be inside a directive. Notice how it **works** when used with the controller but **doesn't work** in my example with the directive.

```js
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ngAnimate', 'ngSanitize', 'ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').directive('timeScale',()=>({
  template:  `
  <h1>Scope:</h1>
  <ul>
    <li>format: {{format}}</li>
    <li>dt: {{dt}}</li>
    <li>popup: {{popup}}</li>
    <li>dateOptions: {{dateOptions}}</li>
  </ul>
  <input type="text"
    class="form-control"
    uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}"
    ng-model="dt"
    is-open="popup.opened"
    datepicker-options="dateOptions"
    ng-required="true"
    close-text="Close"/>
  `,

  link: $scope => {

    $scope.format = 'dd-MMMM-yyyy'
    $scope.dt = null;
    $scope.popup = {
      openend: false
    };

    $scope.dateOptions = {
      dateDisabled: false,
      formatYear: 'yy',
      maxDate: new Date(2020, 5, 22),
      minDate: new Date(),
      startingDay: 1
    }
  }
}));
```

```html
<body ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.5.0.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <time-scale></time-scale>
</body>
```

Comment: Please check my updated answer.

Comment: @I.Ahmed I'm attempting to use it now, will update when I get it working

Comment: I just update it 1 min before. you can check also, removed the button.

Comment: @I.Ahmed your solution is good, but unfortunately for myself I didn't realise I was using semantic-ui so I can't use it :( I'll notify the linked question about this answer too

Comment: OK.Notify after submit the question. I shall check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, its possible to use the directive inside a directive. I have modified your code. And its working, please check.

```js
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ngAnimate', 'ngSanitize', 'ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').directive('timeScale',()=>({
  template:  `
  <h1>Scope:</h1>
  <ul>
    <li>format: {{format}}</li>
    <li>dt: {{dt}}</li>
    <li>popup: {{popup}}</li>
    <li>dateOptions: {{dateOptions}}</li>
  </ul>
  <input uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}" type="text"
    class="form-control"
    ng-model="dt"
    is-open="popup.opened"
    datepicker-options="dateOptions"
    ng-required="true"
    close-text="Close" ng-click="open()" />
  `,

  link: $scope => {

    $scope.format = 'dd-MMMM-yyyy'
    $scope.dt = null;
    $scope.popup = {
      openend: false
    };
    $scope.open = function() {
       $scope.popup.opened = true;
    }
    $scope.dateOptions = {
      dateDisabled: false,
      formatYear: 'yy',
      maxDate: new Date(2020, 5, 22),
      minDate: new Date(),
      startingDay: 1
    }
  }
}));
```

```html
<body ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.5.0.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <time-scale></time-scale>
</body>
```